# How to send from one select option to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Possibly) simple jQuery question here. I'm using jQuery UI Dialog, and am putting a confirm into place. Basically, when a user selects a certain option (in combination with other circumstances), I want to be able to send them either back to the last select they had, or if I can't do that, a default one.

There is no "selected" attribute to the option either, which would have been my go-to example. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the js:

```
alert('hey')
if (document.frm.notNull.checked == true) {
    // This is where it ends!
    if ($('input[name=valueTextField]').length > 1) {
        $('#dialog p').empty();
        $('#dialog p').html("You're going to lose your stuff if you do this. You sure you want to?");
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "<spring:message code='dialogBox.cancelConfirmation.YES'/>": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#bottom").css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $('.edit-new').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    $('.edit-trash').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    // if table has more than one row, delete the rest.
                    deleteExtraRows('valueTable');
                    return true;

                },
                "<spring:message code='dialogBox.cancelConfirmation.NO'/>": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                    // Need to revert the user back to where they came from here.
                    $('#control[value=1]').attr('selected', true);
                    // return false;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#bottom").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.edit-new').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.edit-trash').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        // if table has more than one row, delete the rest.
        deleteExtraRows('valueTable');
        return true;

     }
 }​
```

And this is HTML (being rendered dynamically):

```
<div class="lbl">
    <label>Control</label>
</div>
<select style="margin:0 0 0 8px; left:15px; position:relative;" name="control"
id="control" onChange="checkTableVisibility();">
    <option value=1>Check Box</option>
    <option value=0>Dropdown Menu</option>
    <option value=3>Radio Button</option>
    <option value=2 selected="selected">Text Box</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you have any code or sample to justify what you want to do...its bit confusing to figure it out from the above text..

Comment: Sorry about that, added some code to see if it would help! Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code. Hope this might help you

```
##### Jquery Part #####
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var dropdownControl =$("#control");
 var selectedValue = dropdownControl.val(); 
 dropdownControl.change(function(){
  var dropItem = $(this);
  $('#dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
      width: 600,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          'Ok': function(){
                  selectedValue = dropItem.val();
                  $(this).dialog("close");
               },
               'Cancel' : function(){
                     dropdownControl.val(selectedValue);
                     $(this).dialog("close");
               } 
              }
  });
  });
});
</script>


 #### HTML #####
<body>
 <div>
    <select style="margin:0 0 0 8px; left:15px; position:relative;" name="control" id="control">
     <option value=1>Check Box</option>
     <option value=0>Dropdown Menu</option>
     <option value=3>Radio Button</option>
     <option value=2 selected="selected">Text Box</option>
    </select>
 </div>
 <div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
   Do you want to change value ?
 </div>
</body>
```

I wish you could have put more code. I have added some code which might help in you case. Please go through my changes and comments associate with it. I am wrapping you whole code into jQuery ready function. Please let me know if it worked.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var dropdownControl =$("#control");
  var previousValue = dropdownControl.val(); 
  /// Please add above line of code on your jQuery onload section. So that previous value get set, for the first time, whenever dom gets load. so that you can use it for later cases
alert('hey')
if (document.frm.notNull.checked == true) {
  // This is where it ends!
  if ($('input[name=valueTextField]').length > 1) {
      $('#dialog p').empty();
      $('#dialog p').html("You're going to lose your stuff if you do this. You sure    you want to?");
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "<spring:message code='dialogBox.cancelConfirmation.YES'/>": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#bottom").css('visibility', 'visible');
                $('.edit-new').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $('.edit-trash').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                previousValue = dropdownControl.val();
                // please reset previousValue with the new one that you approved to change so that next time when dropdown changes it value it could use it
                // if table has more than one row, delete the rest.
                deleteExtraRows('valueTable');
                return true;

            },
            "<spring:message code='dialogBox.cancelConfirmation.NO'/>": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                // Need to revert the user back to where they came from here.
                $('#control[value=1]').attr('selected', true);
                 dropdownControl.val(previousValue);
                // Please replace dropdown value with the old one if you want to revert changes.
                // return false;
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    $("#bottom").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.edit-new').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.edit-trash').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    // if table has more than one row, delete the rest.
    deleteExtraRows('valueTable');
    return true;

 }
}​ 
});
```

Comment: This is amazing! The only snag that I'm hitting is the fact that the function that is here is running on the drop down change. So when I'm declaring the values in the .ready, they aren't getting pulled into the mail function(previousVal, for instance). It's strange, I know!

Comment: Could you put some more code. I can provide you sample dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose i understand well your question 
my response will be :
 use variable to store the selected value you can do id like this :

```
$("yourSelect").change(function(){
 selected = $(this).val();
});
```

and then you can reset the value on click to a button reset for example

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
  $("yourSelect").val(selected);
 });
```

Comment: Do you really need a hidden form field? Why not just use a variable external to both functions?